# SignalR and MEF

Tags: mef, signalr

I'm trying to create a DependencyResolver for SignalR using MEF.  So far, I have the following:

```
public class SignalRMefDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

    public SignalRMefDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var export = _container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null).SingleOrDefault();

        return null != export ? export.Value : base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var exports = _container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null);
        var createdObjects = new List<object>();

        if (exports.Any())
        {
            createdObjects.Concat(exports.Select(x => x.Value));
        }

        createdObjects.Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
        return createdObjects;
    }
}
```

I think GetService is working but GetServices fails to find exports for IHubDescriptorProvider and IMethodDescriptorProvider - either in MEF or in base.

In my Application_Start I have the following as the 2nd thing that happens - the first being creation of the MEF container:

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new SignalRMefDependencyResolver(MefConfig.Container));
```

I've also tried:

```
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalRMefDependencyResolver(MefConfig.Container);
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

with the same result.

Am I missing something obvious here?  All the samples I have found are for other containers and seem a lot more complicated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's not working? How is it failing?

Comment: A logical question :) When I step through the resolver, it's returning null for those two interfaces.  Also, my hub doesn't get created when I try to start it from the client.

Comment: Are you sure the objects are in your MEF container? What is your MEF setup like? (What is your setup for [Import] and [Export] stuff?)

Answer (score 2):

looks like the problem here is your use of 'Concat()' - it returns a new collection, rather than changing the collection it is called on.

Answer (score 1):

The Linq-to-objects operators (Concat is one of them) are side-effect free which means that when you do `createdObjects.Concat(exports.Select(x => x.Value));` the concatenation does not take place on createdObjects instead it will take place when you decide to enumerate on the result of the `Concat`. It is a deferred operator as almost all the other Linq operators that return `IEnumerable<T>`. Have a look at the [classification of Standard Query Operators by manner of execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx).

Now for your code to work, try the following:

```
public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
    var mefExports = _container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null);

    //We need this because 
    var dependencyResolverServices = base.GetServices(serviceType);
    if (dependencyResolverServices == null)
    {
        dependencyResolverServices = Enumerable.Empty<object>();
    }

    return mefExports.Select(x => x.Value).Concat(dependencyResolverServices);
}
```

You need to check the return value of `base.GetServices` because [DefaultDependencyResolver's](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Infrastructure/DefaultDependencyResolver.cs) `GetServices` can return null.

Then all you have to do is enumerate the result of your `GetServices`.